Python - Selenium - How to find XPATH FOR A SPECIFIC ITEM
I have a web page that I was able to traverse to multiple pages... Now I need to select a specific item/button from web page that has a list of items. Not sure how to find that item using XPATH or CLASS OR etc., based on the INSPECT VIEW.
def select_requested_colony(colony):
    #//*[@id="zd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p[2]

    try:
        print("================== select_requested_colony ==============")
        print(f"Find Colony: {colony}")
       
        time.sleep(2)

        xpath = f"//*[@id=\"zd\"] //*[contains(text(), '{colony}')]"
        print(f"XPATH: {xpath}")
        
        # Wait for the element to be clickable
        colony_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
        )
        print("FOUND Colony....")
        print(f"Button Text: {colony_button.text}")
        colony_button.Click()
    
        time.sleep(20)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"select_requested_colony -- An error occurred: {str(e)}")


OUTPUT WAS:
================== select_requested_colony ==============
Find Colony: Big Rose, MT
XPATH: //*[@id="zd"] //*[contains(text(), 'Big Rose, MT')]
FOUND Colony....
Button Text: Big Rose, MT
select_requested_colony -- An error occurred: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Click'


Tried multiple ways to find button.

the clue is in the error. try .click() instead of .Click()

Please don't wrap large blocks of text in try-except... when you do that, you lose the stack trace which tells you exactly what happened, on which line, and which part of that line. You may not yet know HOW to use the stack trace but you should spend some time and learn because it will become invaluable in debugging this and future issues yourself.

If you do use try-except, do it for a specific reason... to handle a specific exception, don't catch Exception... that's way too broad.

In answer to finding an element's xpath, you can simply in your browser:

right-click on the element and choose 'inspect'. This will open the devtools window.
Now right-click the element highlighted (or another element if the wrong one is highlighted)
Select copy > copy xpath

In reference to the error you received, however, there is a different reason for this. You have written:
colony_button.Click()

Whereas in Selenium it should be:
colony_button.click()

(Lowercase 'c')

Thanks for your input on the use of try/except blocks.  I change it to lowercase click .... I get the following error message:
select_requested_colony -- An error occurred: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (638, 799)

The XPath for one of the items in the list was:
//*[@id="zd"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p[2]
for JS path...
document.querySelector("#zd > div:nth-child(2) > div.w > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > p.nf")
for the selector:
#zd > div:nth-child(2) > div.w > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > p.nf
OF COURSE THESE WILL BE DIFFERENT FOR EACH OF THE ITEMS IN THE LIST...
So how to get a "CLICKABLE" item??
THANKS

@Patrick not all elements in HTML are clickable, sometimes it may appear that something is clickable and its actually one of its child tags that is handling the clicking, what you're looking for might be a link, input, or a tag somewhere near to the element you're selecting.
